# DataTable already belongs to another DataSet

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable

This error is occuring while adding one datatable from a dataset to another
."DataTable already belongs to another DataSet."

```
dsformulaValues.Tables.Add(m_DataAccess.GetFormulaValues
(dv.ToTable.DefaultView.ToTable(False, strSelectedCols)).Tables(0))
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Like the other responses point out, the error you're seeing is because the DataTable you're attempting to add to a DataSet is already a part of a different DataSet.

One solution is to [Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy%28VS.90%29.aspx#Y0) the DataTable and assign the copy to the other DataSet.

```
dtCopy = dataTable.Copy()
ds.Tables.Add(dtCopy)
```

The copied DataTable will have the structure and data of the copied DataTable.

If you only want the structure of the DataTable, call [Clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone(v=VS.90).aspx) instead.

```
dtCopy = dataTable.Clone()
```

Comment: do you know why this is the case ? Meaning e.g. List<string> myl = new List<string>(); and then i add 3 items and i do this myl[0] = myl[1] and this works fine. I have already added the myl[1] to the list.  Question is more generic on Datatable on why and how this check is done if the table is already belongs to Dataset

Comment: Copy has a lot of overhead... see Nathaniel Layton's answer below for a better solution.

Comment: This works but it shouldn't be the accepted answer...see Nathaniel Layton's answer.

Answer (score 42):

The accepted answer isn't very good. Cloning should always be a last option.

Here's a way around the problem without incurring the overhead of cloning.

```
        DataSet ds = GetData1();

        DataSet ds2 = GetData2();

        //Assuming you know you've got good data

            DataTable dt = ds2.Tables[0];
            ds2.Tables.Remove(dt);
            dt.TableName = "PortedTable";//you may need to change the table name to prevent conflicts
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

Comment: @Layton May I know what is the issue with `Clone` ?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer... copy has a lot of overhead.

Comment: This is like a cut and paste. You remove it from one DataSet and then add it to another. Is there a way in which we can keep the same table in both datasets without cloning?

Answer (score 2):

Try calling this method:

`DataTable dt = dv.ToTable.DefaultView.ToTable(False, strSelectedCols)).Tables(0).Clone()`

This will create a copy of the `DataTable` and assign it to the target `DataSet`:

`ds.Tables.Add(dt)`

Comment: Thanks abbas I have got it :)

Comment: Clone will copy only the structure. .Copy() will copies schema as well as data

Answer (score 0):

I guess this means the DataTable belongs to another DataSet...

You can serialze the DataTable to XML, then deserialize it into your target DataSet.

Comment: i am just adding one datatable of a dataset to another dataset. for this we need to use serializtion ?

Comment: A DataTable can't reside in two DataSets. Maybe you can remove it from the first one and add it to the second. I've never tried it.

Comment: dv.ToTable.DefaultView.ToTable(False, strSelectedCols)).Tables(0).Clone()) is worked for me Thanks for ur reply

Answer (score 0):

I think u should create a new DataTable and import the struct and data to the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy the table with [DataTable.Copy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy.aspx) method in case it's not a typed DataSet. This method creates a new instance of the same table so it not gonna belong to any DataSet:

dim newTable as DataTable = oldTable.Copy()
dim dv as DataView = newTable.DefaultView

dsformulaValues.Tables.Add(m_DataAccess.GetFormulaValues(dv.ToTable.DefaultView.ToTable(False, strSelectedCols)).Tables(0))

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it using `Remove`. In my opinion, **your code** could be this:

```
dsformulaValues.Tables.Add(m_DataAccess.GetFormulaValues
(dv.ToTable.DefaultView.ToTable(False, strSelectedCols)).Tables(0))

dsformulaValues.Tables.Remove(//I'm not sure to understand your code, so read this code line as only an input for your stuff. Please, consider my code below for more understanding.
```

**My** working **code** was like this:

```
DataTable myTable = new DataTable();

private void Save()
{
    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    myDataSet.Tables.Add(myTable);
    myDataSet.Tables.Remove(myTable);//This works
    myDataSet.WriteXml("myTable.xml");
}

private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          Save();
        }
```

Every time I clicked the button `buttonSave`, the message “DataTable already belongs to another DataSet" appeared. After writing the line code  `myDataSet.Tables.Remove(myTable);//This works` the application started running without problems and now I can click the button more times, without losing the value of `myTable` and without the error message.

I hope this can help.

Comment: Sorry, `myDataSet.Tables.Remove(myTable);//This works` line code (in my code above) must be AFTER `myDataSet.WriteXml("myTable.xml");` I confirm that the code works.

Answer (score 0):

I found one turn around I hope it can help

```
_DataTable.TableName = _TableName
If _DataTable.DataSet IsNot Nothing Then
    _DataSet = _DataTable.DataSet
Else
    _DataSet = New DataSet
    _DataSet.Tables.Add(_DataTable)
End If
```

Somehow even if _DataTable is new, but if it refers to a previous loaded physical table it becomes that DataTable inheriting the previous configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is just merge the table as follows.

`dsformulaValues.Merge(m_DataAccess.GetFormulaValues(dv.ToTable.DefaultView.ToTable(False, strSelectedCols)).Tables(0))`

Answer (score 0):

dtCopy = dataTable.Copy()

ds.Tables.Add(dtCopy)

**We can Optimize the  code like :**

ds.Tables.Add(dataTable.Copy());