# DataTable belongs to another Data set / Saves extra Entries in XML

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I know this question has been asked and answered specifically [Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830901/datatable-already-belongs-to-another-dataset)

```vb
ds.Tables.Add(dt.copy)
ds.Tables(0).TableName = "Items"
ds.WriteXml("Inventory.xml")
```

dt.copy does resolve the "DataTable belongs to another Data set" message but when it does save, it of course screws with the XML file and saves extra entries in file, so when the Data Grid loads the XML file it shows entries that weren't there before. Here's my code.

```vb
Try
    dt = New DataTable()
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    'dtcopy = dt.Copy()
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Product_Name", Type.GetType("System.String")))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Product_SKU", Type.GetType("System.String")))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("product_Price", Type.GetType("System.Decimal")))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("product_Quantity", Type.GetType("System.Int32")))

    Dim i As Integer
    i = pInventory.Rows.Count
    i = i - 1

    For Each pRow In pInventory.Rows
        If i <> 0 Or i > 0 Then
            For Each pCell In pRow.Cells
                If IsDBNull(pCell.Value) = True Then
                    If pCell.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
                        pRow.Cells(0).Value = "(Name)"
                    End If

                    If pCell.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
                        pRow.Cells(1).Value = "(SKU)"
                    End If

                    If pCell.ColumnIndex = 2 Then
                        pRow.Cells(2).Value = 0
                    End If

                    If pCell.ColumnIndex = 3 Then
                        pRow.Cells(3).Value = 0
                    End If

                End If
            Next
            fillRows(pRow.Cells(0).Value, pRow.Cells(1).Value, pRow.Cells(2).Value, pRow.Cells(3).Value)

            i = i - 1
        End If
    Next
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    ds.Tables(0).TableName = "Items"
    ds.WriteXml("Product.xml")
    'MsgBox("Done")

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

[I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uRUq.png)

Here's the result when loading the XML up to a dataset into the Datagridview (Inventory). The Empty cells weren't there before, only after the grid gets reloaded.

Here's the code for loading the XML into the DataGridView

```vb
Dim xmlFile As XmlReader
xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("Product.xml", New XmlReaderSettings())
Dim ds As New DataSet
ds.ReadXml(xmlFile)
pInventory.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
xmlFile.Close()
```

I've gone through most of the other posts about this, though while they fix the Table message problem, they don't have any specifics regarding the effects on the table themselves. If anyone can help me, I'd appreciate it.... A LOT!!

```
Private Sub fillRows(ByVal pName As String, ByVal pSKU As String, ByVal pPrice As Decimal, ByVal pQuantity As Integer)
    Try
        Dim dr As DataRow
        dr = dt.NewRow()
        dr("Product_Name") = pName
        dr("Product_SKU") = pSKU
        dr("product_Price") = pPrice
        dr("product_Quantity") = pQuantity
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

This is what the XML looks like when working correctly.. When it doesn't it will show new entries but only 2 column (price and quantity) will have the 0's in them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="true"?>

-<NewDataSet>    
-<Items>

<Product_Name>Harry Potter</Product_Name>    
<Product_SKU>546826584</Product_SKU>    
<product_Price>10.99</product_Price>    
<product_Quantity>2</product_Quantity>

</Items>


-<Items>

<Product_Name>The Last Samurai</Product_Name>    
<Product_SKU>326548742</Product_SKU>    
<product_Price>12.99</product_Price>    
<product_Quantity>1</product_Quantity>

</Items>


-<Items>

<Product_Name>(Name)</Product_Name>    
<Product_SKU>545625986</Product_SKU>    
<product_Price>5.79</product_Price>    
<product_Quantity>5</product_Quantity>

</Items>


-<Items>

<Product_Name>(Name)</Product_Name>    
<Product_SKU>365989568</Product_SKU>    
<product_Price>3.99</product_Price>    
<product_Quantity>3</product_Quantity>

</Items>


-<Items>

<Product_Name>(Name)</Product_Name>    
<Product_SKU>(SKU)</Product_SKU>    
<product_Price>0</product_Price>    
<product_Quantity>0</product_Quantity>    
</Items>  

-<Items>    
<Product_Name>(Name)</Product_Name>  
<Product_SKU>(SKU)</Product_SKU>    
<product_Price>3.99</product_Price>    
<product_Quantity>3</product_Quantity>    
</Items>    
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: A copy is a copy.  Check that the empty cells are not in the source, if you save from the source DT, what does the XML look like?  Also what does `fillRows` do?

Comment: I suggest you write the data with the schema as in  ds.WriteXml(FileName, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema); Now when you read the databack, it would know about the column types. Also, set the DataSource of the DGV to null before you assign it.

Comment: How would I go along setting it to null before I assign it? At the top of form1_load I put    pInventory.DataSource = DBNull.Value.

Comment: use schema : ds.WriteXml("Inventory.xml").  The read doesn't know if data is strings or numbers so without schema errors sometimes occurs on the reads.  You can open the xml file with notepad and verify if the errors are occurring on the write or the read.